# How to use BBBadgeBarButtonItem in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, badge

I want badge on a BarButton and I came across [BBBadgeBarButtonItem](https://github.com/TanguyAladenise/BBBadgeBarButtonItem) but I am not sure if this will work in swift or not.

1. is it possible ?
2. if yes how ?

PS I am very new to iOS and swift

When I try to use it like the readme file says, I am getting an error at import line "***Expected Identifier at import declaration***"

Comment: Try it and then ask a question if you run in to a specific problem.

Comment: adding a import statement is failing for me, when I write 

import "BBBadgeBarButtonItem.h" in my view controller.swift

i get an error "Expected identifier in import declaration"

Is it because when I dropped the files in my project it did not ask for bridge file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need what's called an Objective-C bridging header since  BBBadgeBarButtonItem is written in Objective-C and your project is Swift.

See http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/ on how to create the bridging header.

Once you've properly created your bridging header you'll then add the following to it:

```
#import BBBadgeBarButtonItem.h
```

You should then be able to do something like (untested):

```
let customButton = UIButton()
let barButton = BBBadgeBarButtonItem(customUIButton: customButton)
barButton.badgeValue = 1
```

Comment: That works like charm, thanks. I already had a bridge-header file for some other library, just added the import statement to it.

Comment: the badgeValue would be as String

Answer (score 2):

Import it in you bridging header like this:

```
#import <BBBadgeBarButtonItem/BBBadgeBarButtonItem.h>
```