# Add Badge count icon on BarButtonItem Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, badge

I want to add a badge icon on an icon which i have used in `UINavigationBar`.

This is so far i have done

```
let threeDotButton = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named: "ic_more.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(DashboardViewController.threeDotImageClick))
    let notificationButton = UIBarButtonItem(image:UIImage(named: "ic_notifications.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(DashboardViewController.notificationImageClick))
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [threeDotButton,notificationButton]

    let title = UILabel()
    title.text = "Dashboard"
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: title)

    if let fontstyle = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 30) {
        self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: fontstyle]
    }
```

I want to add count badge on notifcation button . I searched about it but i am not getting a proper solution about it . can anyone explain me how to do it and achieve it

Comment: I encourage you to look into UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIView). Compose your custom view (3dot overlayed by a badge) and pass it as argument.

Comment: i am sorry i did not understood that

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/TanguyAladenise/BBBadgeBarButtonItem try this pod it may satisfy your requirement but its written in objective C but fairly easy to use !!!

Comment: ok i am not familiar with objective C . i try to do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30563283/10132608

Comment: try this its easy